# How can I work with Nested Objects in Loopback 4 using the cli b4 model command

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I'm working with deep nested objects that I need to model for using lb4. Any chance I can get help with this sample JSON code?

`{
"cardAcceptor": {
"address": {
"city": "Foster City",
"country": "RU",
"county": "San Mateo",
"state": "CA",
"zipCode": "94404"
},
"idCode": "ABCD1234ABCD123",
"name": "ABCD",
"terminalId": "ABCD1234"
},
"destinationCurrencyCode": "840",
"markUpRate": "1",
"retrievalReferenceNumber": "201010101031",
"sourceAmount": "100",
"sourceCurrencyCode": "643",
"systemsTraceAuditNumber": "350421"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate Models for the nested objects,

for example for above data structure

You can have something like

```
export class CardAcceptor extends Address {

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  address: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  idCode: string

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  terminalId: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<CardAcceptor>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

```
export class Address extends Entity {

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  city: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  country: string

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  county: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  state: string;


  @property({
    type: 'boolean',
    required: true,
  })
  zipCode: boolean;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Address>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

```
export class BaseModel extends CardAcceptor {


  @property.array(CardAcceptor)
  cardAcceptor: CardAcceptor;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  destinationCurrencyCode: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  markUpRate: string

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  retrievalReferenceNumber: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  sourceAmount: string;


  @property({
    type: 'boolean',
    required: true,
  })
  sourceCurrencyCode: boolean;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
    default: [],
  })
  systemsTraceAuditNumber?: string[];


  constructor(data?: Partial<Game>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Is ti possible for the nested model data to be filtered when saving to ignore undefined properties of the nested model? I'm having issues getting it to work.